# Arrange 14 people into groups of 4 such that every person meets once minimum

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

I have 14 people in a room, and a table with 4 chairs in the middle of the room. I want each person to sit at the table with every other person at least once (i.e. they meet every other person in the room by sitting at the table with them, in groups of 4). I'm wondering what the minimum number of groups I need is and how I can find these groups algorithmically.

Weirdly enough this isn't a homework problem, but a family member is trying to organize a zoom call, and as a maths student it has interested me. I've looked around and found this article trying something similar (http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/11/08/placing-your-employees-so-that-everyone-meets/) and considered the social golfer problem ([https://www.metalevel.at/sgp/#:~:text=The%20Social%20Golfer%20Problem%20(SGP,denoted%20by%20the%20triple%20g%2Dp%2Dw.)](https://www.metalevel.at/sgp/#:%7E:text=The%20Social%20Golfer%20Problem%20(SGP,denoted%20by%20the%20triple%20g%2Dp%2Dw.)) but I'm still unsure. I got 23~ with some really disorganized paper scribblings which I now can't decipher.

Comment: Google social golfer problem with language you want to code it in?https://www.localsolver.com/docs/last/exampletour/socialgolfer.html

Comment: If you have only one table, and don't need the 14 people simultaneously, the problem is much simpler. As you can't divide 14 by 4, the smallest set would be 16 people, groups of 4 for 4 "days". Solutions at [mathpuzzle](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html) and interactively at [wolfram](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/).  The program the simpler problem, some simulated annealing technique would work well.  Probably even some random brute force allocations would quickly find a solution.

Comment: @OliverCiappara as I understand it though, the social golfer problem doesn't mandate that everyone should meet everyone else, just that no two people should meet more than once.

Comment: @JohanC but then, each person will not meet each other person at least once?

Comment: Social golfer has a different constraint: each pair of people should meet at most once, we want to meet at least once here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have C_4_14 possible combinations `(14*13*12*11/(4*3*2*1)) = 1001` possible groups of 4.

You want to be sure that you have all the possible pairs C_2_14 `14*13/(2*1) = 91` pairs.

In each group of 4, you have C_2_4 = 6 pairs.

Let's assign a bit for each possible pair (we need a 91 bits integer).
Now each group of 4 can be written as a 91 bit integer signature with only 6 bits set representing the 6 pairs.

The problem now, is to assemble the groups, so that each pair is represented at least once.
This is equivalent to a bitOr operation (no matter whether the pair is in a group **OR** in another group).
And since we want all the pairs to be represented, we want to choose a subset of the possible 1001 groups, such that the bitOr of the subset is 2^91-1 (all pair are represented at least once).

Since we have 91 pairs, 6 pairs per group, `6*15 < 91 < 6*16`, this gives us a lower bound: we need at least 16 groups of 4 to achieve this, maybe more.
At best, we will have 5 pairs of persons meeting twice, at worse, you could have a single pair meeting 6 times.

To solve the problem, we have to choose an indexing of the pairs, for example:

```
(1,2) = 1
(1,3) = 2
...
(1,14) = 13
(2,3) = 14
...
(2,14) = 25
...
(13,14) = 91
```

Here is an example Squeak Smalltalk code for forming the pairs

```
people := #(mary john clara tim julia mike vanessa bob jean harry kim donald morgan roy).
pairMap := Dictionary new: 91.
i := 0.
people combinations: 2 atATimeDo: [:p |
    pairMap at: p copy put: (i := i+1)].
```

Now, for each group of four, we can associate the pair signature:

```
quadMap := Dictionary new: 1001.
iQuadMap := Dictionary new: 1001.
people combinations: 4 atATimeDo: [:q | | j |
    j := 0.
    q combinations: 2 atATimeDo: [:p| j := j bitAt: (pairMap at: p) put: 1].
    quadMap at: q copy put: j.
    iQuadMap at: j put: q copy].
```

A very naive solution could be to enumerate the combinations of nGroup of quads until we find a combination covering all the pairs. nGroup would start at 16.

```
allPairs := 1<<91-1.
16 to: 91 do: [:nGroup |
    quadMap values combinations: nGroup atATimeDo: [:g |
        (g reduce: #bitOr:) = allPairs ifTrue: [^g collect: [:signature | iQuadMap at: signature]]]].
```

As you can see, the combinatorial is huge, C_16_1001 = 43,051,823,251,587,106,104,672,087,435,021,150 so above loop probably won't be achieved in a reasonable time, and at this stage we don't even know if there is a solution with 16 groups !

We can try some trivial greedy algorithm instead: choose the next group as one maximizing the number of bits (minimizing the overlapping bits) with the solution signature so far.
Overlapping bits can be counted with a bitAnd operation

```
allPairs := 1<<91-1.
signatureSoFar := 0.
groups := OrderedCollection new.
[ signatureSoFar = allPairs]
    whileFalse:
        [heap := Heap withAll: quadMap values sortBlock: [:x | (x bitAnd: signatureSoFar ) bitCount] ascending.
        groups add: heap first.
        signatureSoFar := signatureSoFar bitOr: heap first].
^groups collect: [:qSig | iQuadMap at: qSig]
```

Running this gives me a solution with 18 groups in a few milliseconds...
Running the greedy algorithm 10000 times with shuffled values gave me no shorter solution (solutions found were between 18 and 20 groups).

Up to you to find if this can be done in less than 18 groups.

Comment: I've never seen this language before. I like your algorithm assigning identifiers to the pairs, it makes sense in a neat way. Do you know how I could run this code to try it out? Fascinating that 18 is possible - I expected the lower bound to be 20!

Comment: Squeak/Pharo are desktop applications. They are open and free. There is also an interpreter based on javascript for the browser. https://squeak.js.org/run/ Click on the Squeak5.0-.... link, and you get a Smalltalk IDE in the browser. Open a workspace, copy the snippets, select all (ALT+a), and inspect the result (ALT+i). Beware, the JS interpreter is very slow compared to desktop app...

Comment: Note: this greedy algorithm is too simplisitic, for example it does rarely find the solution for 16 people, which is 20 rounds.

Comment: Note that we can prove that 18 is a lower bound for 14 participants, so your code effectively finds the best solution (+1). One person must participate at least in 5 groups. 5x14=70. So at best, with no redundancy, the number of groups is 70/4 = 17.5 -> 18 groups, with a few (very few) redundancy.

Comment: @Damien thanks for the hint. The algorithm does not work so well for 16 people. But can be improved with a simple heuristic, like minimizing the max number of group per people as secondary objective in heap sort - it then get the correct solution in 1 case out of 6. One major advantage is its simplicity.